# Sumolib: saving the net

Tags: python, sumo

Is there any way to save changes to the loaded net automatically? Like there is an option for:

```
net = sumolib.net.readNet("net.net.xml")
```

Is there an option to save it like

```
net.saveNet("net.net.xml")
```

To save the whole net loaded, including existing properties and including changes?

Answer (score 0):

No. The preferred and recommended way to write sumo networks is to use netconvert (or netedit which is basically its graphical frontend). Depending on the complexity of your net you could generate some plain xml nodes and edges and send them through netconvert.